# Will my computer run games like Skyrim and BF3 on medium?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, battlefield-3

I have an Intel i3 Dual Core, 8GB of RAM, and a GTX 650 graphics card. I have been recently interested in PC Gaming so I was wondering what games my PC could handle at med/high graphics with at least 60 FPS? What do I need to upgrade if I can't?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking if a specific computer can run certain games.  We don't allow questions asking, "Can I run it?" due to their inability to help other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My computer has 6Gb of Ram, a GTX 670 and a i7 2.67 GHz processor and I am not running always running those game at 60 FPS, in fact, you shouldn't notice a big difference between 60 FPS and 30 FPS. When you watch a movie, most of the time it has been filmed with 29.9 FPS.

For Skyrim, you wouldnt need to upgrade your computer unless you add a lot of mods, then you might need to upgrade your GPU. If you are going with a mod that adds bigger resolution textures, you might want a GPU with more memory.

For Battlefield 3, you should not need to upgrade your computer since you are over the recommended specification for the game. your GPU is one generation over the recommended one and you have two time more RAM than what you need to run the game.

If you wish to take a look at the system requirements for both game, you can follow these links:

[The Elder Scrolls: Skyrim](http://store.steampowered.com/app/72850/)
[Battlefield 3](https://www.origin.com/en-ca/store/buy/battlefield-3/pc-download/base-game/standard-edition)

Most information you need to get in order to know if your computer can run a game is available online with a quick Google search. If you buy your games on Steam, it will always be at the bottom of the page of the game before the reviews.

Comment: The OP wants to know about BF3, not BF4. ;) Both are not available on Steam, though you are perfectly right, a quick google of minimum required specs would have answered the OP's question without them having to resort to Arqade

Comment: Oh wow I think I read too fast. Ill edit my answer for that. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: There is quite a difference between the GTX650 and the GTX670. A low/mid range vs a high end gpu.